# How can we add time information to Aggregate report in csv format in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running a Jmeter test plan through command prompt. Then storing its results to .jtl file. Now next I want to get the aggregate results, so through JMeter plugin Aggregate Report generating the aggregateReport.csv. But I am not getting time details in it. Is there any way to get time details in aggregate report csv. Like in normal if we add summary csv report we do get timestamp in it. So is there any property that we can set to get the time in aggregate report. I am using plugin to generate aggregate report.

```
java -jar D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv D:\JMeter\JMeterTestFiles\aggregatedReport.csv --input-jtl D:\JMeter\JMeterTestFiles\summary.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to reach to any solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

In the `jmeter/bin/ directory` there is a file called `jmeter.properties`. Open it with a text editor and make sure the lines below are uncommented and properly configured:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Comment: hey.. This property is set in my jmeter.properties file. But still not working. I am not generating aggregate report through GUI save as file. I am using the plugin.